# PictureBox image from textbox.Text

Tags: c#, textbox, picturebox

I am trying to load the image from a textbox containing the url but i can't get it working,what can be the problem?

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(TextBox9.Text))
            {
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = TextBox9.Text;
                pictureBox1.Load();
            }
```

EDIT:It seems like that the textbox is empty when it wants to load the url because i am using bindingsource textboxes on the form but whereever i put the code above it won't load :S

Comment: The first problem is, that you don't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: name textbox9.text does not exist in the current context

Comment: the textbox contains a http url and the picturebox should load the image from it

Comment: Have you capitalized it right? Windows forms usually does it in the form textBox9. That error message is saying it can't find a variable called TextBox9

Comment: ok yeah corrected no error now but still not loading the image

Comment: That's odd, the code works for me. Put a debug point inside the if statement, I don't think your file exists, so it's not starting the code

Comment: the problem is that my textboxes are from bindingsource from database on the form and i think the code is always run before the text would appear in the textboxes however if i put it to form_load or anywhere still the same

Comment: Oh, I see, what I did was I double clicked on the textbox and it automatically created a method that was run every time I entered text, and I put the code in there

Answer (score 0):

If the TextBox contains an HTTP URL then `File.Exists()` will fail. Try to simply set the location instead. Remove the if-statement and the call to `Load()`.

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = TextBox9.Text; // Will automatically load the image.
```

The following should display the StackOverflow logo (after a short delay)

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico";
```